# Is it possible to have a private constructor in dart?

Tags: dart

I'm able to do something like the following in TypeScript

```
class Foo {
  private constructor () {}
}
```

so this `constructor` is accessible only from inside the class itself.

How to achieve the same functionality in Dart?

Answer (score 180, accepted):

Just create a named constructor that starts with `_`

```
class Foo {
  Foo._() {}
}
```

then the constructor `Foo._()` will be accessible only from its class (and library).

Comment: How can I write a Unit test for this?

Comment: You will not be able to write a unit test for this private constructor. Remember, test the interface and not the implementation. Since a private constructor will not be accessible from outside the library, testing the private method in a unit test would be testing the implementation and not the interface.

Comment: If this is private then how come I can do `Foo._()` outside of the class without getting an error?

Comment: @Chrillewoodz You can if you try to initialize the class from the same file where it is declared.

Answer (score 30):

A method without any code must be something like this

```
class Foo {
  Foo._();
}
```

Answer (score 23):

Yes, It is possible, wanna add more information around it.

A `constructor` can be made private by using (_) underscore operator which means private in dart.

So a class can be declared as

```
class Foo {
  Foo._() {}
}
```

so now, The class Foo doesn't have a default constructor

```
Foo foo = Foo(); // It will give compile time error
```

---

The same theory applied while extending class also, It's also impossible to call the private constructor if it declares in a **separate file.**

```
class FooBar extends Foo {
    FooBar() : super._(); // This will give compile time error.
  }
```

---

But both above functionality works if we use them in the same class or file respectively.

```
  Foo foo = Foo._(); // It will work as calling from the same class
```

and

```
 class FooBar extends Foo {
    FooBar() : super._(); // This will work as both Foo and FooBar are declared in same file. 
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

you can create following class in order to get a singleton instance

```
class Sample{
    factory Sample() => _this;
    Sample._(); // you can add your custom code here
    static final Sample _this = Sample._();
}
```

Now in the main function you can call the sample constructor

```
void main(){
    /// this will return the _this instace from sample class
    Sample sample = Sample();
```

}

Answer (score -6):

just use abstract class.
Because you can't instantiate abstract class

Comment: private constructed classes and abstract class has totally different use-cases, i.e. how would you construct a singleton instance of your abstract class?