# What is the meaning of `Class._()..property`?

Tags: flutter, dart

What does `._()..` mean in the following code?

```dart
class CounterState {
  int counter;

  CounterState._();

  factory CounterState.init() {
    return CounterState._()..counter = 0;
  }
}
```

More precisely - what do the two dots `..` mean past `._()`?

Comment: check [A tour of the Dart language](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour)

Comment: thanks. "The cascade ( .. ) operator can be used to issue a sequence of calls via an object."

Comment: sure, your welcome

Answer (score 5):

### Cascade notation (..)

In the [Dart Languague tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#cascade-notation-), which you should really check out because it contains a lot of useful information, you can also find information about the *cascade notation* you mentioned:

> Cascades (..) allow you to make a sequence of operations on the same object. In addition to function calls, you can also access fields on that same object. This often saves you the step of creating a temporary variable and allows you to write more fluid code.

As an example, if you want to update multiple fields of your render object, you can simply use the cascade notation to save some characters:

```dart
renderObject..color = Colors.blue
    ..position = Offset(x, y)
    ..text = greetingText
    ..listenable = animation;

// The above is the same as the following:
renderObject.color = Colors.blue;
renderObject.position = Offset(x, y);
renderObject.text = greetingText;
renderObject.listenable = animation;
```

It also helps when you want to **return** an object in the same line as assigning a value or calling a function:

```dart
canvas.drawPaint(Paint()..color = Colors.amberAccent);
```

---

### Named constructors

`._()` is a [*named **private*** constructor](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#named-constructors). If a class does not specify another constructor (either default or named) that is *not private*, that class **cannot** be instantiated from outside of the library.

```dart
class Foo {
  Foo._(); // Cannot be called from outside of this file.

  // Foo(); <- If this was added, the class could be instantiated, even if the private named constructor exists.
}
```

[Learn more](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55143244/6509751) about private constructors.

Answer (score 3):

`..` This called [cascade-notation](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#cascade-notation-)

> Cascades (..) allow you to make a sequence of operations on the same object.

In addition to function calls, you can also access fields on that same object. **This often saves you the step of creating a temporary variable and allows you to write more fluid code.**

Example

```
querySelector('#confirm') // Get an object.
  ..text = 'Confirm' // Use its members.
  ..classes.add('important')
  ..onClick.listen((e) => window.alert('Confirmed!'));
```

Answer (score 3):

`CounterState._();` is the named constructor for the class.and `..` is called cascade notation.Means we are creating the Object through the Constructor then we are setting the `counter` as 0.

Answer (score 1):

### **1. Private Constructor**

According to dart documentation, your dart app is a library so even if you create a private constructor for a class, it is accessible in the whole application as it is considered as the library. So, it is not like the other OOP languages.

if you just want to prevent instantiation of class the [read this article](https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/dart-prevent-instantiation-of-class)

### Dart concept for private: [Source](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#important-concepts)

Unlike Java, Dart doesn’t have the keywords public, protected, and private. If an identifier starts with an underscore (_), it’s private to its library. For details, see Libraries and visibility.

According to dart documentation

### Libraries and visibility : [Source](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#libraries-and-visibility)

The import and library directives can help you create a modular and shareable code base. Libraries not only provide APIs, but are a unit of privacy: identifiers that start with an underscore (_) are visible only inside the library. Every Dart app is a library, even if it doesn’t use a library directive.

### **2. Cascade Operator:** [Source](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#cascade-notation)

**..(property)** is used to initialize or change the values of the properties.

According to me, the best use case for this would be that if you are creating an object and you want to initialize other properties that you can not initialize through the constructor there you can use it.

For example,

```
var obj = TestClass(prop1: "value of prop 1", prop2: "value of prop 1")
                  ..prop3="value of prop 3";

// which improves the readability of the code with lesser code and less effort.
```

---